# Use of 'EnvironmentInjector'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

After creating a project with Ionic with Angular (my first try):

```
ionic start app-test tabs --type=angular --capacitor
```

The follow code appears in my project and I don't understant what is  its purpose.

```
 public environmentInjector = inject(EnvironmentInjector);
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, EnvironmentInjector, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule, CommonModule],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public environmentInjector = inject(EnvironmentInjector);

  constructor() {}
}
```

Can you give me an example of use case?

Answer (score 0):

The [`EnvironmentInjector`](https://v16.angular.io/api/core/EnvironmentInjector) is a specific type of [`injectors`](https://v16.angular.io/api/core/Injector) that's part of the environment injector hierarchy, which exists outside of the component tree.

They were introduced in v14 with the introduction of standalone components.

You can use an environmentInjector to provide an injection context for example with `runInInjectionContext`.

```
runInInjectionContext(this.environmentInjector, () => {
   const myService = inject(MyService) // injection possible thanks to the injection context provided by the environment injector
})
```